# How to see why a keras / tensorflow model is getting stuck?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

My code is:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
import pandas as pd

X = pd.read_csv(
    "data/train.csv", usecols=['Type', 'Age', 'Breed1', 'Breed2', 'Gender', 'Color1', 'Color2', 'Color3', 'MaturitySize',   'FurLength',    'Vaccinated',   'Dewormed', 'Sterilized',   'Health',   'Quantity', 'Fee', 'VideoAmt', 'PhotoAmt'])
Y = pd.read_csv(
    "data/train.csv", usecols=['AdoptionSpeed'])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(18, input_dim=18, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=100)
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

I am trying to train to see how the various factors (type, age, etc) affect the `AdoptionSpeed`. However, the accuracy gets stuck at 20.6% and doesn't really move from there.

```
Epoch 2/150
14993/14993 [==============================] - 0s 9us/step - loss: -24.1539 - acc: 0.2061
Epoch 3/150
14993/14993 [==============================] - 0s 9us/step - loss: -24.1591 - acc: 0.2061
Epoch 4/150
14993/14993 [==============================] - 0s 9us/step - loss: -24.1626 - acc: 0.2061
```

...

```
Epoch 150/150
14993/14993 [==============================] - 0s 9us/step - loss: -24.1757 - acc: 0.2061
14993/14993 [==============================] - 0s 11us/step

acc: 20.61%
```

Is there anything I can do to nudge to get unstuck?

Comment: Did you normalize your data before feeding to the network? see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896168/tensorflow-i-get-inaccurate-predictions-nan-and-infinite-values-when-trying-t/53896322#53896322) for an example.

Comment: What are the values in your Y? AdoptionSpeed sounds like a continuous value.

Comment: And the values of the loss suggest that the speed is not between 0 and 1 (as your output is a sigmoid activation)

Comment: I did not normalize. I guess I was somewhat hoping that `keras` would be able to do that? `Y` is days until adoption.

Comment: @DanielMöller good point. Would `relu` be a better output?

Comment: You must test. Relu only >= 0. But the nature of your data might show better ideas, possible normalizations, etc.

Comment: How can I normalize the output? It looks like my data is between 0 - 4. So would it make sense to normalize between 0 and 1?

Comment: Probably yes. Divide by 4 and use sigmoid.

Comment: Awesome @DanielMöller. Please post an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the values of the loss, it seems your true data is not in the same range as the the model's output (sigmoid).

Sigmoid outputs between 0 and 1 only. So you should normalize your data in order to have it between 0 and 1. One possibility is simply divide `y` by `y.max()`.

Or you can try other possibilities, considering:

- sigmoid: between 0 and 1
- tanh: between -1 and 1
- relu: 0 to infinity
- linear: -inf to +inf